# Problem using Rectangle class in .NET CORE Class Library

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, .net-core

I am trying to instantiate a **Rectangle** object in a .NET CORE Class Library.

I have already referenced `System.Drawing`. However, I am still getting the error : `The type Rectangle exists in both System.Drawing.Primitives and System.Drawing`. What is the way out?

P.S. : I am using .NET CORE 2.1

Comment: if you fully qualify the class when you execute your `new` wouldn't that clear up the ambiguity?

Comment: Either qualify fully or, much better, use a short  name (alias) in the using clause to qualify!

Comment: Used both : `System.Drawing.Rectangle` and `using Rectangle = System.Drawing.Rectangle`. The error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it like:

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle();
```

instead of

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
```

or if you don't need `System.Drawing.Primitive` just don't import it.

Comment: Tried using fully qualified class name. Did not help. Also, I did not import `System.Drawing.Primitives`

Answer (score 0):

If you need a namesapce with elements with the same names as elements in `.Net Core` you can either **qualify both fully** or change one of the [`using clauses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) with an **alias** like so:

```
using SD = System.Drawing;  // pick a short but sufficiently clear name
```

and then use it to qualify all elements in `System.Drawing`:

```
SD.Rectangle rect = new SD.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Tried these both. Did not help.

Comment: Doubtful. Do show all relevant code, ie the using clauses and the 1st line that throws the error message! __Note__: The 2nd code in your comment of the question is not at all what I suggested! It is not about a `using variable` clause in the code but about `using alias =  namespace`clause at the top!!